# snmp4j commandresponder as ItemReader for springBatch job

Tags: spring, spring-batch, jobs, snmp4j

I wanted to have spring batch for alarm received through commandResponder ( processPDU) implements as ItemReader for  my springbatch job. I am new to spring , Can someone pls guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The aim of spring-batch is to make a bulk processing. In your case you can have an alarm at any time so the batch should be running and the reader should sleep until receiving a new alarm. So I don't think that Spring-batch is suitable for your case.

You can process the alarms asynchronously through a broker or using `@Asynch` annotation.

Comment: It is async but there can be flooding of alarms at time ( restart system) and my process needs to convert snmp alarm to some other format and send to RabbitMQ hence some procesing is involved. In case of flooding of alarm, I though batch processing might be good.

Comment: It's recommended always to use a broker in order to persist data then you can use any processing method you want after. I think that the conversion of alarm into a broker message will be lighter then processing the alarm it self. Kafka or RabbitMQ can manage a high message rate then if you want you can use AmqpItemReader if you want.